# Search WebList for particular item count from Excel sheet

Tags: vbscript, listbox, qtp

I need a help in VBScript or either in QTP for the below case.

For example:

I have nearly 40 items in the weblist. I have only one item in the Excel sheet that is one among the 40 in the weblist. If I run the script, the one in the Excel should be select in the weblist. How do I perform this? I tried many scenarios, but couldn't get it to work.

Below are some of the sample pieces of code I tried in QTP:

```
ocount=Browser("name:=brw").Page("title:=brw").WebList("htmlid:=tabContainerBrandSite_123&rtyoh").GetROProperty("items count")

msgbox ocount

var7=mySheet2.Cells(2,"C")

For k=2 to ocount 

ocount2=Browser("name:=brw").Page("title:=brw").WebList("html id:=tabContainerBrandSite_123&rtyoh").GetItem(k)

msgbox ocount2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
merchantName = DataTable("Merchant_Name","Global") 'an example if value is saved in global sheet
items_count =  Browser("Sarit").Page("Sarit_2").WebList("txtVendorCode").GetROProperty("Items Count")  'This will get all the items from your weblist.

i = 1
Do

    webListName = Browser("Sarit").Page("Sarit_2").WebList("txtVendorCode").GetItem(i)
'this will get first value from the web list 
    If merchantName = webListName Then  'comparing first value from your value from global sheet
        Browser("Sarit").Page("Sarit_2").WebList("txtVendorCode").Select(i) 'selects that value
        Exit do 'because it has found your only value from the local sheet, it exits
        else
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop While i <= items_count
```